# Perl regex - exponential values

Tags: regex, perl, match, exponential

What's a good regex to match a decimal number to check that it does not contain exponential values?

Thanks for any help.

Can I just say something like match anything except if it contains "e-", "e+", "E-" or "E+"?

Comment: Basically avoid #.####e+## pattern? `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/` should do the trick.

Comment: How does `qr/^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/` (or trivial variants, for non-optional parts) fail?

Comment: The thing is its a cost field, and can contain currency symbols, parenthesis and other characters like that.

Comment: Well, if by "exponential values" you mean 10e7, 10e-7, or 10e+7, then you can look for things that *don't* match `qr/\d+e[-+]?\d+/i`. Of course, there are many ways to write exponential values.

Comment: Heh, I know this is not what you're looking for, but `/^[^\x{2070}\x{2074}-\x{207b}\xb2\xb3\xb9]*$/`. SCNR ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is its a cost field, and can
>   contain currency symbols, parenthesis
>   and other characters like that

Without detailed specs it's not an easy task using regular expressions. In my opinion, regex is inappropriate when you know so little about the format of your input.

---

Update after OP's edit:

> Can I just say something like match
>   anything except if it contains "e-",
>   "e+", "E-" or "E+"?

That would be e.g. `^(?!.*[eE][+-]).*$` (using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), but probably matching more than you like…

Answer (score 2):

This is not the shortest solution, but check the correctness of the whole number...

```
if( $num =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/ ) {
    #correct floating point
    if( $num =~ /e/i ) {
        #exponential
    } else {
        #not exponential
    }
}
```

Comment: That'd not allow his "currency symbols, parenthesis, and other characters like that"

Answer (score 0):

While it's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for, you might want to take a look at the [`Regexp::Common` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/), which is available from CPAN, specifically at [`Regexp::Common::number`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/number.pm). It might offer what you're after.